# ENOENT: Node.js script, fs.rename, to divide and move files from 1 folder to multiple other folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, enoent

I am stuck with my script.
My goal is: I have a folder of images and want to divide and move them to multiple other folders (which are always there).
The folder limit is 200 files and in my loop, after the first folder is succesfully filled with 200 files, at the 2nd file of the 2nd folder I get always the error:

```
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/.../chunkDirsMoveFiles/input/resize/20150818_051550_web.jpg' -> './output/dir_2/20150818_051550_web.jpg'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: '/home/.../chunkDirsMoveFiles/input/resize/20150818_051550_web.jpg',
  dest: './output/dir_2/20150818_051550_web.jpg'
}
```

My code for that (I guess the problem start generally at currentdir = 1):

```
const { clear } = require("console");
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
// const { fileSystemHelper } = require('../allhelpers/fileSystemHelper.js')

const dirLimit = 200

clear()

// Fn to get all file paths of the input folder
const getAllFiles = function(dirPath, arrayOfFiles) {
  files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)

  arrayOfFiles = arrayOfFiles || []

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    if (fs.statSync(dirPath + "/" + file).isDirectory()) {
      arrayOfFiles = getAllFiles(dirPath + "/" + file, arrayOfFiles)
    } else {
      arrayOfFiles.push(path.join(__dirname, dirPath, "/", file))
    }
  })
  
  return arrayOfFiles
}

const images = getAllFiles("input/resize")

const dirAmount = Math.round(images.length/dirLimit)

for (let i = 0; i < dirAmount; i++) {
  fs.mkdir(`./output/dir_${i + 1}`, function(err) {
    // if (err) {
    //   console.log(err)
    // } else {
    //   console.log("New directory successfully created.")
    // }
  })
}

currentDir = 1

for (let i = 0; i < dirAmount; i++) {

  for (let k = 0; k < dirLimit; k++) {

    const theFilePath = images[k].split('/')
    const newPath = theFilePath[(theFilePath.length)-1]

    fs.rename(images[k],  `./output/dir_${currentDir}/${newPath}`, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('Successfully renamed/moved!')
    })

  }
  currentDir += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the loops: for each directory, you take at most `< dirLimit` files and move them all to that directory (so 200 first files). Then, for the next directory, the loop does the same: takes 200 files from the start of the array... but hey! The files were already moved to the previous directory in the previous iteration.

The loop doesn't use `i`, and it doesn't advance through the list of files.

Comment: Ah right. I assumed, the files are gone, so he would look again into the dir and takes the next ... but actually he does not ... 'cause I would need to call the getAllFiles function again, right?

Or add a counter for the files, too

Probably it s safer, if I take the images array and start of slicing that and then move the files around.

I try both.

Thanks a lot, that is super helpful feedback and made the weekend for a rookie.

Comment: @Ehrlich_Bachman Yes, there's no magic here - you tell the code to take *file names* from an array, and the names in the array are not tied to their filesystem counterparts' fates. Slicing is probably the best solution - no need to re-check files when you know which ones you've already moved. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, that does make sense – now. Thanks again.